# kotlin.UInt cannot be cast to kotlinx.cinterop.CValuesRef

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

Uncaught Kotlin exception: kotlin.ClassCastException: kotlin.UInt cannot be cast to kotlinx.cinterop.CValuesRef

Using below code in Kotlin Multiplatform for SSL pinning for iOS.

SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust!!, result as CValuesRef)

Answer (score 2):

One cannot cast the value to the pointer type. You got to allocate native memory, put the value into it, and then pass the pointer to this memory into the function. It the end, it has to look somehow like:

```
memScoped{
    val nativeResult = alloc<SecTrustResultTypeVar>()
    nativeResult.value = result
    SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust!!, nativeResult.ptr)
}
```

Here I allocated memory in the `memScoped` block, so it will be free'd automatically when the block finishes. Please try this approach and tell if something will go wrong, ok?

Comment: I am also getting crash on this line "val remoteCertificateData : NSData = SecCertificateCopyData(certificate) as NSData" . Uncaught Kotlin exception: kotlin.TypeCastException

Comment: I am not sure one can do such casts even in the Swift, according to [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html). 
In two words, you should process casts like that(CoreFoundation <-> Foundation) via special functions, `CFBridgingRelease` here, IIRC. 
A similar question was already discussed [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/3524), it is Kotlin/Native official issue tracker.